# Am I able to use each_cons(2).any? with hash values?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

If I have an array of integers and wish to check if a value is less than the previous value. I'm using:

```
array = [1,2,3,1,5,7]
con = array.each_cons(2).any? { |x,y| y < x }
p con
```

This returns true, as expected as 1 is less than 3.

How would I go about checking if a hash value is less than the previous hash value?

```
hash = {"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2","2"=>"3","4"=>"1","5"=>"5","6"=>"7"}
```

I'm still learning Ruby so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your hash contains strings, your array integers. Is this by design? Also since hashes are considered to be unordered, do you mean sorted by key? Those would sort better if integers.

Comment: Hashes are ordered by insertion in Ruby 1.9+

Comment: @Max: Hashes preserve insertion order, but it is still generally a bad idea to treat them as an ordered collection IMO. (I actually think it was a bad idea to give them this half-baked ordering behavior, because it makes it work in simple cases and either be awkward or unexpectedly break in more complex ones rather than just being consistent, but that horse got out of the barn long ago.)

Comment: @Chuck I agree, but that's what the question is about. tadman made it sound like the question was not well-defined, I was simply pointing out that it is well-defined thanks to insertion order being preserved

Comment: Apologies, I have already converted them to an integer as I have `{1=>564}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find out whether all elements meet the criteria, starting with an array:

```
array = [1,2,3,1,5,7]
con = array.each_cons(2).all? { |x,y| x < y }
con # => false
```

Changing the array so the elements are all less than the next:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
con = array.each_cons(2).all? { |x,y| x < y }
con # => true
```

A lot of the methods behave similarly for array elements and hashes, so the basic code is the same, how they're passed into the block changes. I reduced the hash to the bare minimum to demonstrate the code:

```
hash = {"3"=>"3","4"=>"1","5"=>"5"}
con = hash.each_cons(2).all? { |(_, x_value), (_, y_value) |  x_value < y_value }
con # => false
```

Changing the hash to be incrementing:

```
hash = {"3"=>"3","4"=>"4","5"=>"5"}
con = hash.each_cons(2).all? { |(_, x_value), (_, y_value) |  x_value < y_value }
con # => true
```

Using `any?` would work the same way. If you want to know whether any are `>=`:

```
hash = {"3"=>"3","4"=>"1","5"=>"5"}
con = hash.each_cons(2).any? { |(_, x_value), (_, y_value) |  y_value >= x_value }
con # => true
```

Or:

```
hash = {"3"=>"3","4"=>"4","5"=>"5"}
con = hash.each_cons(2).any? { |(_, x_value), (_, y_value) |  x_value >= y_value }
con # => false
```

---

> I'm creating the hash by

```
stripped = Hash[x.scan(/(\w+): (\w+)/).map { |(first, second)| [first.to_i, second.to_i] }]
```

> I'm then removing empty arrays by

```
new = stripped.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }
```

This isn't a good way to use `scan`. Consider these:

```
'1: 23'.scan(/\d+/) # => ["1", "23"]
'1: 23'.scan(/(\d+)/) # => [["1"], ["23"]]
'1: 23'.scan(/(\d+): (\d+)/) # => [["1", "23"]]
```

In the first, `scan` returns an array of values. In the second, it returns an array of arrays, where each sub-array is a single element. In the third it returns an array of arrays, where each sub-array contains both elements scanned. You are using the third form, which unnecessarily complicates everything done after that.

Don't complicate the pattern passed to `scan`, and, instead, rely on its ability to return multiple matching elements as it looks through the string and to return an array of those:

```
'1: 23'.scan(/\d+/) # => ["1", "23"]
```

Build on top of that:

```
'1: 23'.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) # => [1, 23]
Hash[*'1: 23'.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)] # => {1=>23}
```

Notice the leading `*` inside `Hash[]`. That "splat" tells Ruby to burst or explode the array into its components. Here's what happens if it's not there:

```
Hash['1: 23'.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)] # => {} # !> this causes ArgumentError in the next release
```

And, finally, if you don't need the hash elements to be integers, which contradicts the hash you gave in your question, just remove `.map(&:to_i)` from the examples above.

Comment: I'm creating the hash by `stripped = Hash[x.scan(/(\w+): (\w+)/).map { |(first, second)| [first.to_i, second.to_i] }]` I'm then removing empty arrays by `new = stripped.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }` I'm then looking to return the key of the first hash value that is less than the previous hash value

Comment: what would the best way to loop through the hash and return the key of the first value that is less than the previous value. I was using `.each_cons(2).any? { |x,y| y < x }` previously. But I cant seem to construct it correctly to loop through a hash

Comment: It's basically the thing. You want to "*find* the key of the first value..." so look through the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html) class, and read the descriptions of the methods until you "*find*" one that returns the first matching condition. Note: Stack Overflow is not about handing out code, it's about helping you solve problems, so you need to try, then ask a question when your attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, isolate the values from the hash:

```
values = hash.map { |key, value| value.to_i } #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7]
```

or:

```
values = hash.values.map(&:to_i) #=> to_i is a shortcut for:
values = hash.values.map { |value| value.to_i }
```

and then do the same thing you did for your array example.

Comment: The `to_a` call is redundant in this case.

Comment: to_a converts the hash to a double array, where each array element is the key and the value. @tadman yeah you're right, removed it, .map seems to convert it behind the hood.

Comment: Yeah, `map` is pretty handy that way.

Comment: How about `hash.values`? Or `hash.values.map(&:to_i)` if you must convert them.

Comment: added those as well, not sure if he'd get confused by to_i so I added an explanation.